# Should composables return components?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm learning the composition API, coming from a background with Vue 2 and the options API. I recall that within Mixins in the options API, we could not include components.

It seems that when writing custom composition functions, it is indeed possible to include components, and return them from the function.

Should I be doing this? I feel as though it may be bad practice given that Mixins did not allow for this

Comment: A code pattern can be only considered a good/bad practice when it is placed in a specific context. So what is your purpose when returning a component inside a composable?

Comment: For example, if I was using a composable to share code between two components that would otherwise be duplicated, and they share a common imported child component. Would it be bad practice if I was to return that common import from the composable?

Comment: Seems like you need to provide example code, so that is easier to understand for external people.

Comment: It's not bad when you return a component in a composable. But it provides no value in terms of clean code. You can just import the component to each place where you use it. It makes it easier for others to know what that component is when reading your code.